# Why is there no sync callback in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'd like to be able to show a message to the user once a store sync has successful completion. However, there doesn't seem to be any way of using a callback or calling this synchronously. I'm a little surprised this isn't provided out of the box as it must be a common problem.

Is there any work-around for this?

Comment: If nothing else, you can override `sync()` and probably also proxy's `batch()`, to get a sync event in there. If you look at the code, it's probably a case of "ehhhhh, this is getting complicated, screw it" as far as providing a sync event goes. Because syncing has to wait for all the batch operations to finish.

Comment: What if the sync is for one record (e.g. a user's contact details)? Would it be safe for the user to carry on without it really coming back successful? For me, batch operations are unlikely to be used in my app.

Comment: The batch stuff is there because sync updates deleted, new and changed. So it sends out three operations that the proxy batches together. If you're just concerned with one record, then `Model.load()` might be better.

Comment: Ok gotcha, thanks for this. So that might be why model.load has a callback function. If you add your answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Example of simple solution for success callback http://stackoverflow.com/a/27473830/1199820

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took us ages to find a proper solution to this. Finally we added listener to the store's write event what seems to be working properly. As it is needed frequently it has been added to the store prototype as

```js
Ext.data.Store.prototype.syncWithListener = function(onWriteComplete, syncMethod) {

    this.on('write', onWriteComplete, this, {single:true});

    var syncResult = syncMethod ? syncMethod.apply(this) : this.sync();

    if (syncResult.added.length === 0 &&
        syncResult.updated.length === 0 &&
        syncResult.removed.length === 0) {

        this.removeListener('write', onWriteComplete, this, {single:true});
        onWriteComplete(this);    
    }

    return syncResult;
};
```

Comment: One should mention that this is not a replacement for Ext's `callback`, but only for `success`.