# store.sync() callback

Tags: callback, sencha-touch-2, store, synchronization

Is there a callback for store.sync()?

I am trying to do:

```
store.sync(function(){
   alert('1');
});
```

but it does not work.
The store is a local store.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'callback' for sync(). In order to achieve this behaviour, you will need to listen to the store's write event. Check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14322956/1053958).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
store.sync({
    callback: function (records, operation) {
        alert('1');
    }
});
```

Comment: No. That does not work, nothing is happen when I call sync on the store.

Answer (score 0):

There is the way to listen success event

```js
store.on('write', function(){
    alert('ready');
});
store.sync();
```

`write` fires whenever a successful write has been made via the configured Proxy