# Sencha Touch store sync callback

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

My store.sync() can return success:false, and if it does, I would like to use something similar to Ext's `failure` callback to react to the error appropriately, but I did not find a possibility to use any builtin ST functions for this. sync has neither callback nor success nor failure option available in ST.

What did I overlook?

PS: I did find a workaround for `success` callback at [Why is there no sync callback in Sencha Touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014068/why-is-there-no-sync-callback-in-sencha-touch/14322956#14322956) but I need `failure` callback.

Comment: See simple solution for success callback here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27473830/1199820

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now calling Ext.data.Model.save() on all Ext.data.Model instances that are dirty. This won't batch everything neatly together, but in 90% of the cases, only one item is edited anyways. The best is that this allows to check for failure on each and every item, and not only on the whole batch.

Answer (score 0):

store.sync() is not where you need to look. Take a look at the proxy. Most likely you are using an Ajax request and that in turn will deliver a detailed success and failure.